# PHP- Contact form doesn't redirect

Tags: php, html, web-deployment

I have a contact form in a separate file. It receives input from a normal HTML form, verifies if the input is valid and then it sends an email with the input to a certain e-mail address. After sending the email, it should redirect to another page but it doesn't!

Thanks for your help! :)

```
    <?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error =  "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phone_error = "Phone is required";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
      $phone_error = "Invalid phone number"; 
    }
  }



  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'test@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'Test';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
          header("Location: test.php");
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';
      }
  }


}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: here, if condition mail() function may return false.

Comment: does it shows any error.

Comment: It shows the success variable in a separate file. The variable was made to see if it was the "if" returning false.

Comment: No, it does everything normal and returns $success and send the email and everything fine but no redirection.

Comment: did u configure php.ini file for sending email.

Comment: I run it from my hosting and it does send the email. Should i verify???

Comment: are the spaces before `<?php` in your actual file?

Comment: No, that was my error here :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your email is not working successfully.

You can change you code like this.

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)) {
    $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
    $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';
    header("Location: test.php");
    exit;
}
else {
    $success = "Mail sending failed! Please try again.";
    $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';

    //to show error use: echo error_get_last()['message']

    header("Location: test.php");
    exit;
}
```

It's better to use exit after header redirect.

Also check your form submission method. Is it `post` or `get`

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // your rest of the code
}
else {
    echo 'Invalid server request!';
}
```

Also check this condtion

```
if ($name_error == '' && $email_error == '' && $phone_error == '' ){
    //your code
}
else {
    echo $name_error;
    echo $email_error;
    ech $phone_error;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but for some reasons if i use exit after header the page goes blank :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: test@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body,$headers))
 echo "success";
else 
 echo ""failed:
?>
```

This mail functionality redirection working fine. 
    You will one time check it mail (SMTP) enable in your local & online server.